# Django prefetch_related with limit

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Is there a way to tell `prefetch_related` to only fetch a limited set of related objects? Lets say I am fetching a list of users and I know I want to fetch their recent comments. Instead of fetching comments for each user in a loop, I use prefetch_related to pre-fetch them at the time of fetching the users. My understanding is that this will fetch all the comments made by any user present in the result of the original query but I only want to show the latest 5 for each user.

How does this affect the performance if the list of comments is really huge? Is there a way to fetch only 5 comments for each user in a single (or 2) query? It doesn't have to be the same query as the original one for fetching users but that would be nice.

I essentially want to turn this

```
   users = User.objects.all()
   for user in users:
       user.comments.all()[:10]
```

into something like this

```
 User.objects.all().prefetch_related('comments', limit=10)
```

so if a user has 100s or 10000s of comments, they are not all loaded into memory. How would you do something like this in raw SQL?

Comment: I don't think that using prefetch is the good way to do it. In fact prefetch_related does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the joining in Python. It means that you will preload the comments in python and the join will be done from this preloaded list of comments. In your case, to be sure to have the last 10 comments of each user you need to preload all of them

Comment: I can live with one query per relation but one query per object is the real killer.

Comment: I agree, one query per objects is a nightmare. But why not just doing:
`users = User.objects.all().prefetch_related('comments')`
In this case you will perform only 2 queries

Comment: What if the comments table has hundreds of thousands of rows associated with users that are selected? Not a likely scenario for user-comment relationship but very much possible for other situations.

I am worried that fetching all hundreds or thousands of comments and joining them in python for every 10 - 20 users you select (think pagination) will have performance issues.

Comment: Probably my best thing to do in such situations is to cache top commets in something like redis or denormalize for top 10 comments.

Comment: This is why you can't use prefetch_related and pagination within the same view. It prefetches the _entire queryset_ before it limits the main query. That's not good.

Comment: Can the Prefetch object in 1.7 help somewhat with this? Maybe a queryset with reverse? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: It's gonna be fixed at Django 4.2, see [issue whick fixed #26780](https://github.com/django/django/commit/242499f2dc2bf24a9a5c855690a2e13d3303581a). Let's wait for the release, until then, I suggest using subquery too.

Answer (score 44):

I think there is a workaround now to in django new version as we have OuterRef and Subquery.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Prefetch

subqry = Subquery(Comment.objects \
    .filter(user_id=OuterRef('user_id')) \
    .values_list('id', flat=True)[:5])

User.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('comments', queryset=Comment.objects.filter(id__in=subqry)))
```

Comment: Did you see [horrible](https://gist.github.com/akoidan/25a0b87784cb49a1365c6751d43a4305) sql it generates? Have you checked the performance with it?

Comment: @deathangel908 I am not sure if any better sql can be generated in order to achieve nested limited rows under the main list of results.
I just figured out a way to achieve nested query limit in Django ORM.
If you think of any better raw sql please do share we might be able to figure out a way to generate the Django ORM code for it.

Comment: please take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573615/django-generate-group-by-different-than-id

Comment: @haseebahmad How can I use this hack if I need to limit prefetch that I pass into prefetch_related_objects function?

Comment: @Desh I think you can pass same
"Prefetch('comments', queryset=Comment.objects.filter(id__in=subqry))"
to prefetch_related_objects  as a second parameter.
Have not tested it yet but I think it will work

Comment: Generate error in MySQL: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`

Comment: 6 years later in 2021 this still looks as the only solution. Shame it is not selected as the best answer. Maybe not the most elegant but the only one I found that works.

Django ticket linked above that is 5 years old is not active for last 2 years. And the only solution given is the same as here also by haseebahmad

Comment: @Rockallite ever find a solution to that?

Answer (score 12):

The only way to limit the number of prefetched related objects seems to be using Prefetch() and filtering on fileds. Using sliceing

```
User.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('msg_sent', queryset=UserMsg.objects.order_by('-created')[:10]))
```

returns an error

```
AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

The only way to limit the number of related objects seems to be using filter on a value, for example

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
timelimit = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)

User.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('msg_sent', queryset=UserMsg.objects.filter(created__gte=timelimit)))
```

While that doesn't return a fixed number, in may be useful in some situation, and it will reduce the number of prefetched objects.

Comment: Here is a ticket about `Prefetch` object not accepting querysets with slices: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26780

Comment: [Already working in Django 4.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/4.2/#models) but it's in beta as of now

Comment: This last tiny comment should be the accepted answer now xD

Answer (score 4):

thats what actually works for me django(2.1) (based on [haseebahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3298249/haseebahmad) answer).
in order for prefetch_related to accept customize queryset: Prefetch
so:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery ,Prefetch

User.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('comment_set',  
queryset=Comment.objects.filter(id__in= 
Subquery(Comment.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('user_id')).
values_list('id', flat=True)[:1]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do by using `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.db.models.functions.window import RowNumber
from django_cte import With

cte = With(
    Comment.objects.annotate(
        row_number=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(),
            partition_by=F("user_id")
        )
    )
)
qs = cte.with_cte(cte).filter(row_number<=10)
users = User.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("comments", queryset=qs, to_attr="limited_comments")
)
```