# Get only one related object from Django queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to optimize a feed-like query in Django where I get the unique items commented by users I follow.

```
        queryset_comments = Item.objects.distinct() \
        .prefetch_related('comments', 'comments__user') \
        .filter(comments__user__in=self.request.user.following.all()) \
        .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('comments', queryset=Comment.objects.filter(
                user__in=self.request.user.following.all()
            ).order_by('-created_on'), to_attr='activity')
        ) \
        .all()
```

This gives me a related `activity` object with a list of all the comments made by user I follow, with the most recent comment first. Now I only need the first one, so I loop other the queryset and set the values I need:

```
        for item in queryset_comments:
            item.feed_user = item.activity[0].user
            item.feed_date = item.activity[0].created_on
            item.feed_activity = 'commented'
```

But this loop is taking more than 2 seconds with only about 500 items... I've tried to prefetch with slicing (by adding `[0]` or `.first()` to the `Prefetch` queryset, but both methods are unsupported by Django ORM.

Any suggestion to make this a bit faster ?

Comment: Have you already tried `earliest` or `latest`?

Comment: Try using `latest_activity = item.activity.first()`  just after the `for` loop and then use this `latest_activity` object to set other values on `item`.

Comment: @2ps: got same error as whenI use slicing: `AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute '_add_hints'`

Comment: @Rahul: `item.activity` is a list, I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'first'`. I tried with `latest_activity = item.activity[0]`, it works but it takes the same time.

Comment: In the end I'll go for a cache/redis denormalization to speed up feed retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

There was a simliar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24690755/5520354) that made me come to the same conclusion.

I would suggest to not use `prefetch_related`, but to finish working your queryset until its ready to execute the database query. Maybe even paginated, so you only have 20 or 50 objects.

Then make a list of all `Item.pk` values and fetch the related "one comment per Item" yourself (using `Max('created_on')` ).

Same thing as `prefetch_related` but more control.