# Prefetch object and slice

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to do a slice inside a Prefetch object

```
  def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('products', queryset=Product.objects.order_by('-updated_at', '-created_at')[:3]))
```

but I get the following error:

```
Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

I found the following post about it: [prefetch_related with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690755/django-prefetch-related-with-limit,)
but the solution, doesn't work in my case, using timedelta you don't know how many you get.

Also the question is more than 3 years old, so I hope, in meantime some solutions, changes to Django occurred(something that support multiple databases)

In the tracker there is a solution using Window:

```
Prefetch(
    'post_set',
    queryset=
        Post.objects
        .annotate(_rank=Window(Rank(), partition_by='category')
        .filter(_rank__lte=3)
)
```

but I don't know the Window support besides PostgreSQL, and don't know wher to find Rank.

I'm taking in consideration if using extra can help.

Comment: This is not currently supported - see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26780

Comment: There's now a solution in the question you've linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944361/4744341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through comments of what you've linked. It seems that people in the project are aware of the issue. [Look here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26780). [This comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26780#comment:6) suggests finding a workaround to limit the query.

Comment: I saw the comment, but I don't know the support of the function at the database level; I update the question to be more clear.