# Django generate group by different than id

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to count amount of Users for same Product

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
   pass
class User(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

User.objects.filter(age__gt=18).annotate(product_count=Count('product_id'))
```

**output sql**

```
SELECT
  "user"."product_id"
  COUNT("user"."product_id") AS "product_count"
FROM "user"
WHERE "user"."age" > 18
GROUP BY "user"."id";
```

**desired sql**:

```
SELECT
  "user"."product_id"
  COUNT("user"."product_id") AS "product_count"
FROM "user"
WHERE "user"."age" > 18
GROUP BY "user"."product_id";
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that makes any sense. What you want is probably this:

```
Product.objects.annotate(user_count=Count('user'))
```

Comment: more specifically, `Product.objects.annotate(user_count=Count('user')).values('id').order_by('id')`

Comment: I don't know if django makes any sense, but query makes a lot of sense, what if I need to filter object somehow, in your case it will perform the inner join. Check my edits, please

Comment: @Selcuk check my edits please, how do I filter user by age using your answer? Furthermore, I need to select user fields, not product, why would I perform operations on `Product.objects` and then join user, when I don't need to fetch product fields at all?

Comment: You can filter users by age using filter parameter : `Product.objects.annotate(cnt=Count('user', filter=Q(user__age__gt=18)))`.