# Django ORM: Get all records and the respective last log for each record

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have two models, the simple version would be this:

```
class Users:
    name =  models.CharField()
    birthdate =  models.CharField()
    # other fields that play no role in calculations or filters, but I simply need to display

class UserLogs:
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(to='Users', related_name='user_daily_logs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reference_date = models.DateField()
    hours_spent_in_chats = models.DecimalField()
    hours_spent_in_p_channels = models.DecimalField()
    hours_spent_in_challenges = models.DecimalField()
    # other fields that play no role in calculations or filters, but I simply need to display
```

What I need to write is a query  that will return all the fields of all users, with the latest log (reference_date) for each user. So for n users and m logs, the query should return n records. It is guaranteed that each user has at least one log record.

Restrictions:

- the query needs to be written in django orm
- the query needs to start from the user model. So Anything that goes like Users.objects... is ok. Anything that goes like UserLogs.objects... is not. That's because of filters and logic in the viewset, which is beyond my control
- It has to be a single query, and no iterations in python, pandas or itertools are allowed. The Queryset will be directly processed by a serializer.
- I shouldn't have to specify the names of the columns that need to be returned, one by one. The query must return all the columns from both models

Attempt no. 1 returns only user id and the log date (for obvious reasons). However, it is the right date, but I just need to get the other columns:

```
test = User.objects.select_related("user_daily_logs").values("user_daily_logs__user_id").annotate(
    max_date=Max("user_daily_logs__reference_date"))
```

Attempt no. 2 generates as error (Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field):

```
logs = UserLogs.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-reference_date')[:1]
users = Users.objects.annotate(latest_log = Subquery(logs))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems impossible taking into account all the restrictions.

One approach would be to use `prefetch_related`

```
users = User.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch(
        'user_daily_logs',
        queryset=UserLogs.objects.filter().order_by('-reference_date'),
        to_attr="latest_log"
    )
)
```

This will do two db queries and return all logs for every user which may or not be a problem depending on the number of records. If you need only logs for the current day as the name suggest, you can add that to filter and reduce the number of UserLogs records. Of course you need to get the first element from the list.

```
users.daily_logs[0]
```

For that you can create a @property on the User model which could look roughly like this

```
@property
def latest_log(self):
    if not hasattr('daily_logs'):
        return None
    return self.daily_logs[0]
 
user.latest_log
```

You can also go a step further and try the following SubQuery inside Prefetch to limit the queryset to one element but I am not sure on the performance with this one (credits [Django prefetch_related with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690755/django-prefetch-related-with-limit)).

```
users = User.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch(
        'user_daily_logs',
        queryset=UserLogs.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(UserLogs.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('user_id')).order_by('-reference_date').values_list('id', flat=True)[:1] ) ),
        to_attr="latest_log"
    )
)
```