# Django Display multipe categories on page

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model.py file:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(default='default_thumbnail.png', upload_to='thumbnails')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
        #null=True,
        default=1,
        verbose_name="Category"
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Each video has its own category and I want to display on one page a given number of films in **each category**.

Currently, I'm only showing the last 5 videos on the page:

```
def home(request):
    latest_videos = Video.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')[:5]

    categories = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
        'latest_videos': latest_videos,
        #'categories': categories,
    }
    return render(request, 'videos/home.html', context)
```

I have no idea how to display a given number of movies in each category. I tried to send all the videos and query them on the template, but this is probably impossible.

Any ideas? I'm still learning Django, but this time I found a problem I can't solve all day.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django prefetch\_related with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690755/django-prefetch-related-with-limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how many categories do you need to show in your template but one way to do this is like:

```
def home(request):
    ready_data = []
    all_categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related('video_set').all() # Note that video_set is your default related query name
    for _c in all_categories:
        related_videos = _c.video_set.all().order_by('-date_posted')[:5]
        ready_data.append({"category_id": _c.id, "category_title": _c.title, "related_videos": related_videos})

    context = {
        'data': ready_data 
    }
    return render(request, 'videos/home.html', context)
```

And you should also change this part of your template to something like:

```
{% for d in data %}
<p> category: {{ d.category_id }}, {{ d.category_title }} </p>
{% for v in d.related_videos %}
<h3> Videos </h3>
<p> {{ v.id }}- {{v.title}} </p>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This way you can show each category and 5 last of it's related videos.